# Could we ask the team for a way to cloud-seed the front page?

Tags: discussion

Given the low rate at which good questions arrive, the front page tends towards a population of less-than-exemplary questions. Is anyone interested in asking the SE team if we could somehow pick out a dozen questions that are smack-dab in the center of what we like, and have them be what shows up when a new visitor shows up?

Comment: My understanding of the sorting is limited, but if I'm not mistaken, recently edited or answered questions bubble up. Perhaps the community can make these kinds of questions active.

Comment: FWIW, we have an option that does *exactly this* - and it was turned on for most sites for a while. [Folks didn't care for it, since the site looked "static"...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182973/the-frontpage-for-anonymous-users-is-too-static)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this. I think it is based on a misconception though?

Really new users and visitors are extremely unlikely to see the front page: 99% of visits are direct links to questions or answers, and the vast majority of those are direct from Google.

The front page is really there for established users like us, those who have at least started rooting around to see what else is on the site. As Ray mentioned in his comment, it's a tool to help us see what's been recently asked, edited or answered and review or contribute ourselves. As such it's performing it's purpose well even if it does tend "towards a population of less-than-exemplary questions": It's helping us be aware of quality issues on the site and stimulating debate.

Comment: It's quite interesting to look down the [list of new users](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) and see how many have no other SE account. However I was referring to more to what the question calls "new visitor[s]" which I think means the whole body of folk who visit the site, not just those who sign up: we have [120 users with 200+ rep and 3500 visits/day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics).